# what is the best way to take the backup of data of sqlite3 database of iphone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, backup

i want to take the backup of all the data in the database of my  iphone app in dropbox and restore it later.here the main problem is there is too much data in the app so if i am using sql queries to fetch data from sqlite3 database and storing it into the file and again reading data from that file and inserting it to database.can anyone suggest that how can i improve that or what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that you mean that you want to be able to restore the data after user has somehow deleted the application and re-installed it again. Since each application has its influence inside the bounds of its sandbox, the only sane option would be to use server. In regards to simply answering your question - there is no way to do it as you've described.

Comment: can we store the data in dropbox and retrieve it later without using server?

Comment: Yes, but it actually is a web service, which you wanted to refrain from. You are being contradictory.

Comment: and what if i want to restore data only when application is installed.in application user can delete the data.and later i want to restore the data which user has deleted from the app.here keep the case aside when user had uninstalled the app.

Comment: Listen to what Alex said below, iCloud is a very nice option I forgot to mention. As for how to restore the data if app has been installed - look into using NSUserDefaults. When the app is launched first time, restore all the needed data and set some bool sentinel into the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

You can use iCloud.
Go to your app manager on Itunes Connect to generate a iCloud Key.
So, all data will be stored on icloud.

Comment: How can we do this through iClould, would you please give us some useful links to us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can find all informations about this here: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use too a uuid as Key for your webservice. So, if the use delete app and when he reinstall, you cad download all data with key identifier.

For example:

```
uuid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier];
```

With [Class for UUID](https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5)

Important: Use the global mode because it allows to use the uuid between applications.

Answer (score 0):

my dropbox-based [Sync API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/sync/docs/ios)  solution:

```
- (IBAction)onTouchDropboxBackup:(id)sender {

    DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkedAccount];

    if (account) {

        if (![sharedDelegate filesystem]) {

            DBFilesystem *filesystem = [[DBFilesystem alloc] initWithAccount:account];
            [DBFilesystem setSharedFilesystem:filesystem];
            [sharedDelegate setFilesystem:filesystem];
            [filesystem release];
        }

        DBPath *destination = [[DBPath root] childPath:kDataDBFileName];
        DBError *error = nil;

        //check presense
        DBFile *file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] openFile:destination
                                                       error:&error];
        if (error){//not present

            [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] createFile:destination
                                              error:&error];

            file = [[DBFilesystem sharedFilesystem] openFile:destination
                                                   error:&error];
        }

        if (!error) {

            [file writeContentsOfFile:[DOCUMENTS_DIR stringByAppendingPathComponent: kDataDBFileName]
                          shouldSteal:NO
                            error:&error];

            [file update:&error];
            [file close];
        }

    }else
        [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] linkFromController:self];
}
```